# ValueError: Unexpected option 'height' for Points type when using the 'matplotlib' extension. No similar options found

Tags: matplotlib, gis, geopandas, geoviews

I am trying to do this project in the link. But various errors first concerning the library installation to now this value error. I am writing the code as how it is shown in this link. But unable to run.

First error:

```
Unexpected option 'height' for Points type when using the 'matplotlib' extension. No similar options found.
```

Second error:

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

Link: https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-geospatial-data-visualization-with-geoviews-in-python-7d5335c8efd1

[![

```
zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I6nc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I6nc.png)

[![

```
Unexpected option 'height' for Points type when using the 'matplotlib' extension. No similar options found.
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJrEK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJrEK.png)

I have tried writing same code in the link which is provided. I even tried using a different dataset but everything seemed to be not working. These codes are important while doing a GIS problem.

Comment: Use the same versions of packages and libraries that the original code used... Suggestion: use virtual environments too.

Comment: But without a virtual environment, there shall be some solution right> I have used these few to install the library. conda update --all
conda install -c pyviz geoviews
conda install -c scitools cartopy
conda install -c pyviz gdal
conda install -c pyviz bokeh

Comment: Yes, there must be a solution without a virtual environment... It was just a tip... About package/libraries versions, It may be that the original code does not use the latest version... For example: the latest version of `geoviews` is 1.9.5. Are you sure the original code also uses 1.9.5? There are versions 1.9.4, 1.9.3, 1.9.2 and so on...

Comment: Yes, I knew about the virtual environment solution before, which I didn't want to try. But your point is right about the version. I can see that the blog was made on March 2020, so probably the version shall be something then or before. But I am unable to find out that version number from the internet.